# Simulating a location on Real iOS Device

Tags: iphone, ios, location, device

Is it possible to simulate a location on iOS Device, say I want to simulate London on the device while I am sitting in Oxford?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example https://github.com/iam4x/pokemongo-webspoof

Answer (score 21):

Yes, It is possible to simulate the location on device in debug mode. All you need is to debug your application on device, and then enable the location from debug menu.

Check this link...
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html

Comment: Thank you Yasir. Can I simulate it on device without debugging. I want to simulate location without connecting device to my machine

Comment: There is a trick, maybe if that works for you, i.e. Simulate location for any test project, then disconnect your device and start using your app which you want to debug without connecting.

Comment: For this purpose you have to set the default location for a test project. => Create your test project
=> Set default location by editing schema (Product->Schema->Edit Schema->Run(left panel)->Options (tab)-> Check the 'Allow Location Simulator')
=> Select location from drop down
=> Debug test project on device
=> Disconnect the data cable and then start testing you desired app.

I hope this trick may work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a GPX file with the desired location/coordinates and you can enable it from the debugger or from the Project scheme select run/options/"Allow location simulation".
After you have this enabled and your device connected the location simulation will work on the device to till you reboot it.
A good article that explain this can be found here: https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this project can help: https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator
It simulate location sending fake data to the coreLocation.