# How to debug location change on ios with a physical device (no simulator)

Tags: ios, core-location

Is their anyway on a physical device to simulate movement and thus location change? i need to debug my app that is running under ios to test if everything work fine, even when the app is in background mode.

Comment: You can use the "simulate location" menu item on the Debug menu in Xcode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating a location on Real iOS Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436495/simulating-a-location-on-real-ios-device)