# CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation not working for simulated location

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, location, clgeocoder

I enabled location simulation from scheme of Xcode checking `Allow Location Simulation` and selecting sample location from dropdown - `New York, NY, USA`.

This is my code to fetch place informations from location.
`currentLocation` is got from `CLLocationManager` and I see the value is exactly got as `NewYork` location.

```
- (void) fetchPlacemarks: (CLLocation*) currentLocation
{
  // Reverse-geolocate the current location
  CLGeocoder* geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
  [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: currentLocation
                 completionHandler: ^(NSArray<CLPlacemark*>* placemarks,
                                      NSError*               error)
   {
      // getting error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"
   }
}
```

I've tested by Simulator and device with real location(not simulating) but they works like a charm.

Only it doesn't work in device with simulating location.
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

On a real device, you can simulate only through the debugger, look here:

[Simulating a location on Real iOS Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436495/simulating-a-location-on-real-ios-device)

Comment: Yes. I run the app as debug mode. I get my current location exactly as simulated location(New York).

Comment: Set default location by editing schema (Product->Schema->Edit Schema->Run(left panel)->Options (tab)-> Check the 'Allow Location Simulator') => Select location from drop down => Debug test project on device => Disconnect the data cable and then start testing you desired app

Comment: No, it's not the answer.